# GeoFireStore query always returns {}

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, geofirestore

I've written 2 Firebase Functions to:

1, let users check into a location

2, query for locations nearby

The checkin code is:

```
.https.onRequest(async(request, response) =>{
     const uid = request.query.uid
     const cat = request.query.cat
     const addr = request.query.add
     const name = request.query.name
     const long = Number(request.query.long)
     const lat = Number(request.query.lat)
     const gpoint = new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(lat,long)
     const db = admin.firestore()
     const tstamp = Date.now()
     const adata = {
        createdate: tstamp,
        checkins: 1,
        lastcheckin: tstamp,
        status: null,
        createdby: uid,
        category: cat,
        address: addr,
        name: name,
        lat: lat,
        long: long,
        gid: null,
        g: {
          coordinates: gpoint,
          
        },
       }
      await db.collection('places').add(adata)
      response.send('OK')
  })
```

This works well:
[image]

My query function for finding places nearby using GPS coordinates is:

```
.https.onRequest(async(request, response) =>{
     const long= Number(request.query.long)
     const lat = Number(request.query.lat)
     const GeoFirestore = require('geofirestore').GeoFirestore
     const database = admin.firestore();
    const geofirestore = new GeoFirestore(database);
    const Geo = geofirestore.collection('places')
    const query = Geo.near({center: new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(lat,long), radius: 10 })
     query.get()
      .then((snapshot: { data: () => any }) =>{
       // const data =(snapshot.data())
        response.send(snapshot.data())
     })
       .catch((error: any) => {
           console.log(error)
           response.status(500).send(error)
       })
        })
```

When I run the query in my browser .../getplaces?long=46.93351240000001&lat=13.1321528

it always returns {}

Where am I going wrong?

TIA

Comment: DB img has been updated, the longitude and latitude were the wrong way around in the GeoPoint. Now corrected. the result of the query is still empty.